# Option to create docker repository is disabled

Tags: artifactory, docker-registry, jfrog-container-registry, docker-repository

I am using on-prem JFrog Artifactory to hold maven artifacts. I have a need to use this Artifactory to hold my app's docker images. So I tried creating a new docker repository but it showed me docker type as disabled. When I am looking around people are suggesting to use JFrog Container Registry.

Can't I create a docker repository in my existing Artifactory, does it require any plugin etc. to be downloaded to add this functionality in existing Artifactory?

And how to enable that docker repository option while trying to create a new repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using the [Artifactory OSS](https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Artifactory-Oss/view) version and not the Artifactory pro version, Artifactory OSS is limited as this an open-source version for the Maven-based projects. As everyone recommends you can make use of the [JFrog container registry](https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Container-Registry/view) which is free to use application to handle the Docker registries.
Otherwise you can [utilize the FREE Cloud Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/pricing/) to handle all the different repositories in a single Artifactory instance.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am using free version, ok so it looks like there is no way to store docker images on my existing self hosted artifactory (free version).

Comment: new link: https://jfrog.com/container-registry/